# threshold must be numeric and non-NAN, When printing numpy array, Why numpy.nan is undefined in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Im trying to print all the values of a matrix in python2 by

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
print myMatrix
```

but its giving me the error
`threshold must be numeric and non-NAN`

In python3 I can print the array by

```
import sys
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
print(myMatrix)
```

But why numpy.nan isn't working in python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nunmpy.nan` was never [supposed to be supported](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12987). This is why it doesn't work in python 3

Answer (score 2):

The correct is: `np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf, linewidth=np.nan)`